# How to disable error stack trace on client

Tags: meteor

So I created simple Meteor method:

```js
Meteor.methods({
    insertMessage: function(message) {
        check(message, String);

        if (!this.userId) {
            throw new Meteor.Error("not-logged-in", "Must be logged in to create message.");
        }

        if (!message) {
            throw new Meteor.Error("empty-message", "Message cannot be empty string.");
        }

        var id = Messages.insert({
            text: message,
            author: Meteor.user().username,
            createdAt: new Date()
        });

        return id;
    }
});
```

I'm calling it on client side like so:

```js
Meteor.call("insertMessage", message, function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error.reason);
    }
});
```

Everything works awesome. When I'm not logged in I see: "Must be logged in to create message." in console.

BUT!

I also see error stack trace. How to disable it in production. I don't want to show strange stuff in console to users. It works not as an error, just information that I don't want to show.

Thank you.

Comment: My general recommendation is to avoid performing actions on the client which you know will result in errors. In some cases that's unavoidable, but here it's easy enough to conditionally invoke the method.

Comment: Really? So if user send me empty string what should I do? Well I can perform some actions silently, without throwing exceptions, but I think its not a great habit.

Comment: I think your UI should compensate for those things. Imagine a form with a field for a message - maybe the form's submit button is disabled unless the message has a non-zero length.

Comment: UI is the second part. First you make validations and filters on server side. So if someone will use web console or other tool bad data will not be saved into DB. After that you add some UI indicators (disabled buttons, red / green borders and so on). The thing is that I want to throw exceptions if something works not as expected. Then catch them on client side and show some sexy error popup with error reason. And I can do it now, but I don't want to see some debug stuff in console.

Comment: I should have been more clear. I'm not suggesting you remove the validations on the server. The server is the final authority on what gets written to your DB, so it absolutely should throw errors on bad data. I'm simply suggesting the client should not call the method if it knows it's going to fail - that should be the case under normal operation. It seems like you are trying to fix a problem that shouldn't really exist... unless you have a lot of users opening up their dev consoles on your site.

Comment: Well yeah, you are totally right. I really can check message input and if it is empty do not even call meteor method. And in this case I will work as needed. If someone will open web console and try to add data manually and will see error, it's absolutely OK. Why do you use web console in the first place? :D But I'm curious about error stack trace. It's like I'm running app in debug mode.